# Using powershell variables in my python script?

Tags: python, powershell, automation, scripting

I have made a user creation script in powershell, and I am almost done writing the website automation part of it in python with selenium. My problem lies in the joining of the 2. I would like my Python script to use the new user creds I entered in powershell.

So hopefully the PS script would run fully, but before exiting it starts my python script and uses the creds to build him website profiles as well. I have done quite a bit of research the last couple days and cannot figure this out.

Thank you!

Comment: [1] the easiest way to share data back-n-forth is to use JSON or XML. [2] here is a selenium module for PoSh ... that might let you bypass using python.

Comment: You might also look at the snek module by Adam Driscoll. It allows you to use python and PowerShell together in some ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it with passing them only one time rather than saving passwords clear text. Although, if you enable Powershell logging, check what will end up in those logs.

```
$user1 = "test1"
$cred1 = "testpass1"

# you can also concatenate if necessary, adding all users/pws with some separators
$user2 = "test2"
$cred2 = "testpass2" 

$users=$user1+","+$user2 
$creds=$cred1+","+$cred2

PS > py .\path_to\create_web_profiles.py $users $creds  # make sure you use _py_ and not python / python3.
```

create_web_profiles.py:

```
import sys

users = sys.argv[1]
passwords = sys.argv[2]

def getusers(users, passwords):

    users=users.split(",")
    passwords=passwords.split(",")

    print('Usernames: ',users,'Passwords: ',passwords)
    for user,passw in zip(users,passwords):
        create_web_user(user,passw)

def create_web_user(user, passw):
    # your web functions come here
    print(user,passw)
    pass

getusers(users, passwords)
```

Output:

```
PS > py .\path_to\create_web_profiles.py $users $creds
Usernames:  ['test', 'test2'] Passwords:  ['tpass', 'tpass2']
test tpass
test2 tpass2
```

Comment: Great :) Glad to hear.